# I have a trouble in the Log-in procedure of my website

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I having a difficulty on Log-in procedure. The username & password are both correct based on the database. The name of the fields on the database are also correct. I'm using PDO. When I click the log-in, I'm always redirecting to the else bracket. Please help me,thank you.

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 'config.php';

if ($_POST) {
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM useraccounts WHERE USER_NAME=? AND USER_PASSWORD=?";

$stmt  = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt  -> bindParam(1,$user);
$stmt  -> bindParam(2,$pass);
$stmt  -> execute();

$num  = $stmt->rowCount();

if ($num>0) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user']=$user;
    $_SESSION['active']=true;
     header('location:frontpage.php');  //Must be the destination
    echo "SUCCESS"; 
            }
else{
    header('location:login.php'); // <-- I'm always directing here
    echo "FAILED";
    }

}

else{
header('location:login.php');
echo "FAILED";

}
```

Comment: What is `$num`? `var_dump($num);` Do you have error reporting on? I see no difference between the first `else` and the second`, you've debugged to confirm you are in the first `else`?

Comment: do you get a error in your server console?

Comment: Which else are you getting redirected to? Are you sure that you are redirected to the one you pointed out or the outermost one?

Comment: yes, I'm sure. I tried to edit the login.php to index.php and it directs me to index.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting redirected to the login.php page, please keep in mind the following:

1) Unless you access that page with a POST request, you will always get the login.page. You have an if statement that looks like this:

if ($_POST) {

So if you access the page directly from the browser, you are redirected straight to the login.php page.

2) If you are getting redirected from the second else statement like you stated with your comment "<-- I'm always directing here" then your query is not returning any result. Your query looks fine. So check the credentials you are passing. Make sure it matches that of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Is your html form using POST or GET in the method attribute. it should be using POST otherwise your database checking code will not be run